# Chaining together operations on an Option to a Future, then back to an Option?

Tags: scala

I'm writing an authentication client that takes an `Option[Credentials]` as a parameter.  This `Credentials` object has a `.token` method on it which I will then use to construct an HTTP request to post to an endpoint.  This returns a `Future[HttpResponse]`, which I then need to validate, unmarshal, and then convert back to my return type, which is an `Option[String]`.

My first thought was to use a for comprehension like this:

```
val resp = for {
  c <- creds
  req <- buildRequest(c.token)
  resp <- Http().singleRequest(req)
} yield resp
```

but then I found out that monads cannot be composed like that.  My next thought is to do something like this:

```
val respFut = Http().singleRequest(buildRequest(token))

    respFut.onComplete {
      case Success(resp) => Some("john.doe")//do stuff
      case Failure(_) => None
    }
```

Unfortunately `onComplete` returns a unit, and `map` leaves me with a `Future[Option[String]]`, and the only way I currently know to strip off the future wrapper is using the `pipeTo` methods in the akka framework.  How can I convert this back to just an option string?

Comment: What does buildRequest() return? If it is just a Request object, you should be able to use req = buildRequest(c.token) and your code will work. If creds is None, the for expression should fail fast. Otherwise, if you have to start working with nested monads, look at the monad transformers in Cats.

Comment: It returns an `HttpRequest`.  val response = for {
      `c <- credentials
      req = buildRequest(c.token)
      resp <- Http().singleRequest(req)
    } yield resp` gives the following stacktrace: `found   : scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse]
[error]  required: Option[?]`

Comment: The last call in the for comprehension will return Future[HttpResponse], so that is correct, but your method returns an Option[String], which is where the error is from. You can use Await() on the Future to get the result, but this isn't really something you should do in production systems, since it is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've got a `Future[T]`, it's usually good practice to *not* try to unbox it until you absolutely have to. Can you change your method to return a `Future[Option[String]]`? How far up the call stack can you deal with futures? Ideally it's all the way.

Something like this will give you a `Future[Option[String]]` as a result:

```
val futureResult = creds map {
  case Some(c) => {
    val req = buildRequest(c.token)
    val futureResponse = Http().singleRequest(req)
    futureResponse.map(res => Some(convertResponseToString(res)))
  }
  case None => Future(None)
}
```

If you *really* need to block and wait on the result, you can do `Await.result` as described [here.](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking-outside-the-future)

And if you want to do it in a more monadic style (in a for-comprehension, like you tried), [cats has an OptionT type](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) that will help with that, and I think scalaz does as well. But whether you want to get into either of those libraries is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to "upgrade" an `Option` to a `Future[Option[...]]`, so use `Future` as your main monad. And deal with the simpler case first:

```
val f: Future[Option[String]] = 
  // no credential? just wrap a `None` in a successful future
  credsOpt.fold(Future.successful(Option.empty[String])) {creds =>
    Http()
      .singleRequest(buildRequest(creds.token))
      .map(convertResponseToString)
      .recover {case _ => Option.empty[String]}
  }
```

The only way to turn that future into `Option[String]` is to wait for it with `Await.result(...)`... but it's better if that future can be passed along to the next caller (no blocking).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain about what all your types are, but it seems like you want a for comprehension that mixes option and futures.  I've often been in that situation and I find I can just chain my for comprehensions as a way to make the code look a bit better.

```
val resp = for {
  c <- creds
  req <- buildRequest(c.token)
} yield for {
  resp <- Http().singleRequest(req)
} yield resp
```

resp becomes an Option[Future[HttpResponse]] which you can match / partial func around with None meaning the code never got to execute because it failed its conditions. This is a dumb little trick I use to make comprehensions look better and I hope it gives you a hint towards your solution.

Comment: Also, if buildRequest doesn't return an Option type, then you can do "req = buildRequest(c.token) instead.  That is a way a for comprehension can execute code blocks that operate on a non-iteratable which really makes more sense if there is a "convert to iterable" step needed before another nested iteration.